# get second imei number through adb shell

Tags: adb

I was able to get one imei number through adb shell with command

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1
```

But device has two imei numbers ,

How to get second imei number through adb shell

The output of adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 is as below (which is inbetween quotes)

```
Result: 

Parcel(
0x00000000: 00000000 0000000f 00320031 00340033 '........1.2.3.4.'
0x00000010: 00360035 00380037 00300039 00380039 '5.6.7.8.9.0.9.8.'
0x00000020: 00360037 00000035                   '7.6.5... ')
```

imei=123456789098765

Help me to find second imei......

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour) is a question and answer site for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system.

Comment: @Cyrus, this is on topic here. Next time remove the irrelevant tags and move on.

Comment: Sorry for that, please help me to get that second imei number

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get both IMEI with service call iphonesubinfo.

Though the order in which they are fetch is not always definite in my experience, but you can always fetch both and compare to one if you need to.

```
/system/bin/service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 1 | cut -d\' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' | tr -d '\n'


/system/bin/service call iphonesubinfo 3 i32 2 | cut -d\' -f2 | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' | tr -d '\n'
```

You can substitute `/system/bin/service` with `adb shell service` if you are running from adb and not from device shell.

Comment: Hi, your answer is partially incorrect.
On the phones that I have tried the slot index start from 0 and every invalid index is treated as 0, so: i31 0 => slot 1, i32 1 => slot 2, i32 99 => slot 1.
It also depends on the slot support of the phone, if the phone have only 1 slot then every index is the slot 1.
If you are interested my script detect everything automatically: https://github.com/micro5k/microg-unofficial-installer/blob/main/utils/device-info.sh