# How to Get IMEI Number From Adb Command of Higer Level Api Devices

Tags: android, adb

I am working on Adb with my Samsumng Galaxy Device. I want to Get IMEI number of Device using Adb Command but Unable to do that.

I Tried Following:-

```
        adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo
```

but it returns nothing

I also tried with Service Call Command:-

```
     adb shell service call iphonesubinfo
```

but it gives me Strange Result Like this:-

```
   Result: Parcel(                                                        
    0x00000000: 00000000 0000000f 00350033 00390038 '........3.5.8.9.'    
    0x00000010: 00320037 00380030 00350034 00350031 '7.2.0.8.4.5.1.5.'   
    0x00000020: 00300031 00000033                   '1.0.3...        ')
```

Can anybody Help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353640/how-do-i-get-meid-and-imei-information-using-adb-commands-on-android-5-0

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/140356/how-do-we-run-06-using-adb-to-get-imei-number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237850/get-second-imei-number-through-adb-shell

Comment: Already tried these options but nothing is working....i need to get IMEI on Console Application so Dial is not an option for me